# How to obtain WebLogic's commonj.work.WorkManager properties from java code?

Tags: java, jmx, weblogic11g

I am running a web application in WebLogic 11gR1 which makes use of WorkManager. I need to print some properties like: wmName, state, workCount.

This is my java code to get WorkManager info:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
commonj.work.WorkManager wm = (commonj.work.WorkManager) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/MyWorkManager");
```

The problem I am facing is that from my "wm" variable I cannot access the properties I need, the only properties I can access are these:

[image]

But, if I debug it in Eclipse, I can see it contains the properties I need under this structure:

[image]

Could you please explain how to get the properties I need (wmName, state, workCount) ?

Answer (score 0):

mayb a better way should be to use JMX and getting those information from WorkManager [configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/WLMBR/core/index.html) and [runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/WLMBR/core/index.html) mbeans

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will use JMX to get these properties instead.